# WebForm_DoCallback definition

Tags: asp.net, callback

Is there a simple explanation on MSDN of WebForm_DoCallback function?

All I can find is this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163878.aspx
which does include implementation of WebForm_DoCallback but doesn't do a good job explaining parameters themselves.

```
function WebForm_DoCallback(eventTarget, eventArgument, 
eventCallback, context, errorCallback)
```

Like what exactly does it expect as an 'eventTarget'? 
What is 'context'? 
Etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WebForm_DoCallback appears to be the client-side counterpart to [GetCallbackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153106.aspx). It's generated with the same arguments, which are as follows:

> **target**: The name of a server Control that handles the client
>   callback. The control must implement
>   the ICallbackEventHandler interface
>   and provide a RaiseCallbackEvent
>   method.
>
> **argument**: An argument passed from the client script to the server 
>   RaiseCallbackEvent method.
>
> **clientCallback**: The name of the client event handler that receives the
>   result of the successful server event.
>
> **context**: Client script that is evaluated on the client prior to
>   initiating the callback. The result of
>   the script is passed back to the
>   client event handler.
>
> **clientErrorCallback**: The name of the client event handler that receives
>   the result when an error occurs in the
>   server event handler.
>
> **useAsync**: true to perform the callback asynchronously; false to
>   perform the callback synchronously.

**clientCallback** and **clientErrorCallback** are client-side (usually javascript) functions with arguments in the form:

```
function clientCallback(returnmessage, context) {}
```

Where **returnmessage** is the response from the server (or error) and **context** is the same as the **context** passed in previously.

*References:*

[MSDN: ClientScriptManager.GetCallbackEventReference Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153106.aspx)

[MSDN Magazine: Implications of Script Callbacks in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163878.aspx)

[ESRI Developer Network: Page Postbacks and Client Callbacks](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/developer/ADF/pagepost_clientcall.htm)

Answer (score 5):

we can see something like this--

```
WebForm_DoCallback('__Page',parameter,callBack,context,null,false);
```

in the page resource file.
it seems the 'parameter' is a value type(string), while the context is a ref type.
anyway the "context" is rarely used.
the "Parameter" could only be a string, so you may need combine several values into it, and then separate it on the server.
while the data is transmitted to the server end, the relative class(as a subclass of interface '**ICallbackEventHandler**') instant will be created, and the handler method will be called:

```
public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
   //deal with the eventArgument( the "parameter")        
}
```

after that another method goes on and return a string back in the response..

```
public string GetCallbackResult()
{
    //return command;
}
```

finally the async process raises the callback function( "**callBack**" in this case),which should has 2 input params:

```
function callBack(returnedStuff, context) {......}
```

and that's how it works
however I don't know where the javascript function "WebForm_DoCallback" is defined, so it may not work on the non-windows computers.

Answer (score 0):

To what context do you need to use this with?  The string is generated by the following method call in ClientScriptManager: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153110%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Using this is what you can use to produce the above statement, without having to know the details.

HTH.

Comment: I'm actually invoking this function on client side WebForm_DoCallback(...) so I'm supplying all the params. Hence the question.

Comment: I understand.  Sorry I looked for resources for the client method but didn't find any good ones.  In the meantime, to work around that, you can generate the method call on the server and pass to the client, and use something like eval() to evaluate it.